# What minimum Android Studio Gradle/Plugin versions required to target Android 30?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

Is there any **minimum recommended or required Gradle or Gradle Plugin versions** if we intend to target **Android 30**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have reference to this https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin

Answer (score 2):

It is always best to use the latest Gradle and AGP, if you're using Beta or Canary distribution, back down one small version if you encounter errors when compiling.